# How do I separate out fields in a CKRecords results Xcode objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, cloudkit

I have saved data to fields in CloudKit and I have queried for the posts by date in decending order and by getting the one at index(0) I have the last post.  My question is how do I separate out the various fields and use them to populate the text in various labels in my view.  Here is what I have for the latest post query.

```
<CKRecord: 0x104e5b600; recordID=157F08E2-FF00-42DD-8B89-7CB10FAC81B6:(_defaultZone:__defaultOwner__), recordChangeTag=kk6d3s69, values={ temperature=54, trip=50, level=53, battery=64, date=1-20-2021      20:57:09 }, recordType=MyPoolInfo>
```

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  This is a dictionary. So I just called the following:

```
NSLog(@"temperature:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"temperature"]) ;
               NSLog(@"date:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"date"]) ;
               NSLog(@"trip:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"trip"]) ;
               NSLog(@"battery:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"battery"]) ;
               NSLog(@"level:%@",[dictionary objectForKey:@"level"]) ;
```

I could then fill in the label.text like this:

```
self.DateLabel.text =[dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
```

in case anyone needs to know.